# How do i extract values using specific keywords in powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have a powershell script which outputs the below and i want to extract the value corresponding to Total Minutes in the output.

Thanks in advance

```
Hours             : 20
Minutes           : 15
Seconds           : 21
Milliseconds      : 616
Ticks             : 11097216160848
TotalDays         : 12.8440001861667
TotalHours        : 308.256004468
TotalMinutes      : 18495.36026808
TotalSeconds      : 1109721.6160848
TotalMilliseconds : 1109721616.0848
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is likely an object in list form. This means the text left of the colons are the property names. You can reference them in numerous ways.

```
# piping to select-object
$output | Select-Object -Expand TotalMinutes

# using member access
$output.TotalMinutes
```